# Porting Twemoji regex to extract Unicode emojis in Java

Tags: java, regex, unicode, encoding, emoji

I'm trying to identify the same emojis in a String for extraction that [Twemoji](https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.js) would, using Java. A straight up port isn't working for a great deal of emojis - I think I've identified the issue, so I'll give it in an example below:

Suppose we have the emoji  (Codeunits being `\ud83e\ude94`). In Javascript regex, this is captured by, `\ud83e[\ude94-\ude99]` which will first match the `\ude83e` then find subsequent `\ude94` within the range indicated inside the brackets. The same expression in Java regex, however, fails to match at all. If I modify the Java pattern to `[\ud83e[\ude94-\ude99]]`, according to an [online engine](https://regex101.com/), the 2nd half is captured, but not the 1st.

My working theory is that Java encounters the brackets and treats everything inside as a single codepoint and when combined with the outside codeunit, thinks it's looking for two codepoints instead of one. Is there an easy way to fix this or the regex pattern to work around it? The obvious fix would be to use something like `[\ud83e\ude94-\ud83e\ude99]`, the actual regex pattern is quite lengthy. I wonder if there might be an easy encoding fix somewhere here as well.

Toy sample below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String emojiPattern = "\ud83e[\ude94-\ude99]";
    String raw = "\ud83e\ude94";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emojiPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
}
```

Comment: Did you try `[\x{1FA94}-\x{1FA99}]`? (`String regex = "[\\x{1FA94}-\\x{1FA99}]";`)

Comment: That will work for the singular example, but I'm trying to convert many instances/ranges (e.g. `\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c\udffd\u200d\u2764\ufe0f\u200d\ud83d\udc8b\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c[\udffb\udffc\udffe\udfff]`) I suppose I could convert the existing pattern into many ranges, but I'd like to avoid having to expand it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to match a single specific codepoint, don't mess with surrogate pairs; refer to it by number:

```java
String emojiPattern = "\\x{1FA94}";
```

or by name:

```java
String emojiPattern = "\\N{DIYA LAMP}"
```

If you want to match any codepoint in the block U+1FA94 is in, use the name of the block in a property atom:

```java
String emojiPattern = "\\p{blk=Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A}";
```

If you switch out any of these three regular expressions your example program will print 'true'.

The problem you're running into is a UTF-16 surrogate pair is a single codepoint, and the RE engine matches codepoints, not code units; you can't match just the low or high half - just the pattern `"\ud83e"` will fail to match too (When used with `Matcher#find` instead of `Matcher#matches` of course), for example. It's all or none.

To do the kind of ranged matching you want, you have to turn away from regular expressions and look at the code units directly. Something like

```java
char[] codeUnits = raw.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < codeUnits.length - 1; i++) {
    if (codeUnits[i] == 0xD83E &&
        (codeUnits[i + 1] >= 0xDE94 && codeUnits[i + 1] <= 0xDE99)) {
        System.out.println("match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Being bored, I just wrote a java program that reads the UCD.zip file and generates a class with a regular expression that matches any valid emoji based on TR51. It's quite a big RE.

Comment: Is there no way to force RE to use match against codeunits? I'd be curious to see what you used to generate the regex. I considered something similar, but don't know that Twemoji that I'm trying to duplicate matches the spec completely and it looked quite tricky with all the possible variants and combinations.

Comment: I'm surprised it's even possible in JavaScript. Sloppy programming. -- I'll try to upload the source somewhere later tonight.

Comment: @underwhelmed https://gist.github.com/shawnw/e9aee51848da1d374b4d649f9628c97e

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with this a bit, might try to expand the original JS regex expression into something that works in Java or even just run it in a JS engine. This would be a homerun solution if only I didn't need to emulate the same set of emojis as Twemoji, which might not include everything in the spec